How to store and retrieve wix app settings in a custom Wix App?
I'm currently working on a Wix App (Wix CLI / React-style) that will have one or more custom elements. These custom elements have some props that are configurable in the element itself (using panel.tsx).
However, I would also like to give the user of the app/element the ability to configure some props on a global / app level, which would be too tedious to re-configure every time you place the custom element on a page. Examples are global theming (e.g. background color, text color, font-family) or a license key / API secret, and so on.
Coming from a Wordpress background and being new to Wix, I regard a Wix App as analogous to a Wordpress Plugin, and a Wix custom element as analogous to a Block or shortcode. In Wordpress, I would use get_option / update_option (link) for that, but I'm not sure what's the equivalent in Wix if there even is one. As the Wix CLI also generated a dashboard page.tsx for me, I would assume it to be possible to do it in there.
I did find the "Wix Data API", but to me it seems like it's more targeted towards collections and entities than a settings store. I also checked the rest of the Wix documentation, especially the Backend Modules section, but I didn't see anything the looked like a way to store user configurable app settings.
What do you think would be the best practices for storing wix app-level settings?

Ultimately, I went with the Wix Data API although I can't say it was without any problems. The Wix docs aren't always too clear and I received some useless API error messages along the way (WDE0110: Wix Code not enabled.).
An important thing to mention before starting to create and get Collections and Items (basically tables and rows in Wix Data API), make sure to give your app the right permissions. Go to: Custom Apps, select your app, go to Permissions, Add Permissions, and add the following permissions:

Manage Data Collections
Read Data Items
Write Data Items
Manage Your App*
Manage Dashboard*

* I'm not sure if these are really needed.
Install the following npm packages (if not installed already):
yarn add @wix/data @wix/sdk-react @wix/dashboard-sdk @wix/dashboard-react

Import collections and items from @wix/data and useWixModules from @wix/sdk-react:
import { collections, items } from "@wix/data";
import { useWixModules } from "@wix/sdk-react";

Inside of your component you can then get the CRUD methods as follows:
const { createDataCollection, getDataCollection } = useWixModules(collections);
const { saveDataItem, getDataItem } = useWixModules(items);

Define keys that will be used to get the settings collection & item:
const SETTINGS_KEY = "my-app-settings";
const SETTINGS_ITEM_KEY = "my-app-settings-item";

Then, to CRUD collections:
// get collection
collection = await getDataCollection(SETTINGS_KEY);

// create collection
await createDataCollection({
  _id: SETTINGS_KEY,
  collectionType: collections.CollectionType.WIX_APP,
  displayName: "My App Settings",
  fields: [
    {
      key: "licenseKey",
      displayName: "License Key",
      type: collections.Type.TEXT,
    },
  ],
  permissions: {
    insert: collections.Role.ADMIN,
    read: collections.Role.ANYONE,
    update: collections.Role.ADMIN,
    remove: collections.Role.ADMIN,
  }
});

// get item
const item = await getDataItem(SETTINGS_ITEM_KEY, {
  dataCollectionId: SETTINGS_KEY,
})

// create or update (upsert) item
await saveDataItem({
  dataCollectionId: SETTINGS_KEY,
  dataItem: {
    _id: SETTINGS_ITEM_KEY,
    data: {
      _id: SETTINGS_ITEM_KEY,
      licenseKey: "123456",
    }
  },
})

Finally, to make sure your app is authenticated to the Wix Data API, use withDashboard to wrap your Dashboard page: export default withDashboard(Index);
See also this Github Gist
If anyone spots a mistake or knows a better way, please let me know or place a comment / answer. :-)

Hey! Is the license key data that should be publicly available? If so, you did the right thing by using Wix Data.
Otherwise, you might want to use the Secrets API, which allows you to save server-only secret data (https://dev.wix.com/docs/sdk/backend-modules/secrets/introduction)

Hi, LICENSE_KEY was just an example. The app I'm working on in real life uses different settings. Maybe I should have picked a better example

I see. Looks great then!
By the way, the Wix Data API has a "single item mode" that's specifically aimed at singleton data like configs. It creates a collection with a single item and acts like a KV store. Also, if the site owner edits the data via the CMS, it looks like a config page (instead of a table).
You can ready about it in the docs, it's under the plugins field in the createDataCollection method: https://dev.wix.com/docs/sdk/backend-modules/data/collections/create-data-collection
